# Создание бинарной строки из массива для записи в поток

Tags: php, потоки-данных

Здравствуйте.

Такой код:

```
foreach($array as $key=>$el) {
    fseek($r, 3, SEEK_CUR);
    fputs($r, $el, 3);
}
```

Записывает данные в файл, если элемент меньше 3-х байт - остальное заполняется, не знаю как правильно сказать, но наверное, нулевыми байтами. Если открыть файл в Sublime Text:

```
3135 3400 3535 0000 //здесь зашифровано 154 и 55, между ними заполняется 0
```

Дело в том, что массив очень большой, десятки тысяч записей, гонять указатель и записывать тоже приходится десятки тысяч раз. Есть ли способ записать из массива в строку таким же способом? Мне важно, чтобы данные были определенной длины. Т.е. если даже элемент 1 символ (1 байт) - то занимать он должен все те же 3 байта.

**Update:**
Описание задачи: у меня массив чисел, который выходит за рамки доступной памяти. Я его храню в файле, отводя под каждый элемент определенное количество байт. Всё устраивает, но много времени занимает запись. Хочу сделать что-то вроде временного буфера, и записывать элементы по 100, например.

Comment: $array1=array_fill(0,count($array)*3,0);

Comment: А что происходит если элемент не лезет в 3 байта?

Comment: Остальные байты просто не записываются. Т.е. если было `qwerty`, будет - `qwe`

Comment: Вы можете создать длинную строку и работать с ней как с массивом, побайтно. В конце работы сбросить в файл целиком строку

Comment: Опишите полностью задачу. Скорее всего, быстрее (но не проще!) будет сделать AOF + компактирование. Ну и блочную запись никто не отменял, вам не обязательно по одной записи каждый раз менять, можно сразу блоками.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тогда так

```
$out=array();
for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++) {
 $temp=str_split($array[$i]);
 $out[]=$temp[0];
 $out[]=isset($temp[1])?$temp[1]:chr(0);
 $out[]=isset($temp[2])?$temp[2]:chr(0);
}
```

А потом $out в файл

Ну или вместо массива можно строку конкатенатить

Comment: Хм, я ожидал, что Ваш способ будет или такой же, или менее быстрый. Но он примерно в 2-3 раза быстрее чем мой.